# Set the visibility of an array in Kotlin to visible

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I have an array of buttons that I want to hide using .visibility = View.INVISIBLE
But this doesn't work for an array, any guesses on how I could achieve this?

Comment: You have to iterate. It's not the array that you are making invisible. It's each button in the array that you need to make invisible. `for (button in buttonArray) { button.visibility = View.INVISIBLE }`

Answer (score 0):

You should try View.Gone instead of View.INVISIBLE

```
     buttonArray.forEach{
       it.visibility=View.GONE
     }
```